# access data from host in docker container

Tags: docker

New to docker here. I know there's the concept of `volume` in docker for storage of data. I created one empty directory inside docker folder, and added `VOLUME ["/model1/data"]` in the dockerfile. Since the data is pretty large, I don't want to write it into the image. I tried putting the data into the `data` folder after building the container, but there's no data show up inside the docker shell. How can I access the data on my host inside docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I access the data on my host inside docker container?

You can start the container with the volume from host mounted in the container by using `-v` flag.

```
docker run -v "/path/to/host/directory:/path/inside/container" <image_name>
```

This maps one directory from host to container. You can make more mappings by using multiple `-v` flags.

Comment: Nice, though in my case needs a slight modification: add a `-it` flag after `run`